# iPad safe area in Apple Design Resources – iOS 17 and iPadOS 17 (Redable Content Margin and Layout margin for iPad Design)

Tags: ipad

I could n't understand iPad safe area guide lines based on Apple Design Resources especially redable Content Margin and Layout margin for iPad Design,
could anyone please describe it .

Please look into attached image

I tried to understand iPad safe area guide lines based on Apple Design Resources, tried to understand redable Content Margin and Layout margin for iPad Design in figma but not get an clear
idea on it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tNPr.png)